# Summarize data from a list of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dfs, df_list:

```
[   CLASS  IDX  A  B  C  D  
 0     1    1     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  
 1     1    2     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  
 2     1    3     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0,  
    CLASS  IDX  A  B  C  D  
 0     1    1     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  
 1     1    2     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  
 2     1    3     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0,  
    CLASS  IDX  A  B  C  D  
 0     1    1   0.900   0.100     0.0     0.0  
 1     1    2   1.000   0.000     0.0     0.0  
 2     1    3   0.999   0.001     0.0     0.0]
```

I would like to summarize the data into one df based on conditions and values in the individual dfs. Each df has 4 columns of interest, A, B, C and D. If the value in for example column A is >= 0.1 in df_list[0], I want to print 'A' in the summary df. If two columns, for example A and B, have values >= 0.1, I want to print 'A/B'. The final summary df for this data should be:

```
CLASS   IDX 0   1   2
0   1   1   A   NaN A/B
1   1   2   A   A   A
2   1   3   A   A   A
```

In the summary df, the column labels (0,1,2) represent the position of the df in the df_list.

I am starting with this

```
for index, values in enumerate(df_list):
    # summarize the data
```

But not sure what would be the best way to continue..

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I could help you but I don't really understand your question.  Are you able to paste the code to recreate the list of dataframes and show exactly the output you would want and why?  The "for example" bit is too undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there is one approach

```
cols = ['A','B','C','D']

def join_func(df):
    m = df[cols].ge(0.1)
    return (df[cols].mask(m, cols)
                    .where(m, np.nan)
                    .apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1))

result = (df_list[0].loc[:, ['CLASS','IDX']]
                       .assign(**{str(i) : join_func(df) 
                                  for i, df in enumerate(df_list)}))
print(result)
   CLASS  IDX  0  1     2
0      1    1  A      A/B
1      1    2  A  A     A
2      1    3  A  A     A
```

Comment: Great thanks! But my_list_df should be df_list, no?